# Angular not sending http post correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, angularjs

I have this Angular code in a function:

```
function doAjax() {

                $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'http://thatsmyipv4address/MarkBeacons/www/test.php',
                        data: {
                            'dispositivo': getDevice(),
                            'momentoacceso': getMomentoExacto()
                        }
                    })
                    .then(function (data) {
                        alert("Data Saved: " + data.response);
                        console.log(data);
                    }, function (error) {
                        //alert('error: ' + error);
                        console.log('error: ' + error.data);
                    });
            }
```

And when I call `doAjax()` it must send a POST message to my *test.php* with the values of `getDevice()` that returns an String and `getMomentoExacto()` that returns another String.

But when I execute the *test.php*:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "markbeacons");

if(isset($_POST['dispositivo'])) {
  $dispositivo = $_POST['dispositivo'];
} else {
  $dispositivo = 'valor1';
}

if(isset($_POST['momentoacceso'])) {
  $momentoacceso = $_POST['momentoacceso'];
} else {
    $momentoacceso = 'valor2';
}

echo "$dispositivo";
echo "$momentoacceso";

$sql = "INSERT INTO registroEstimote (dispositivo, momentoconexion) VALUES ('$dispositivo', '$momentoacceso');";
```

Why it's inserting me on the data base the else values (valor1 and valor2)?

Comment: check in the network tab of developers tools what data is sent to `test.php`. also if your `test.php` is in the root folder of your project you can just use `url: '/test.php'`

Comment: Check your network console is call sending data correctly to server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The $http.post and $http.put methods accept any JavaScript object (or
>   a string) value as their data parameter. If data is a JavaScript
>   object it will be, by default, converted to a JSON string.

You have forgotten to add this line

```
 headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

```
 $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://thatsmyipv4address/MarkBeacons/www/test.php',
        data:  $.param({
            'dispositivo': getDevice(),
            'momentoacceso': getMomentoExacto()
        }),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        alert("Data Saved: " + data.response);
        console.log(data);
    }, function (error) {
        //alert('error: ' + error);
        console.log('error: ' + error.data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not populating $_POST as you expect.

The POST-data can be achieved this:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

To get the correct fields you have to `json_decode()` it:

```
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$dispositivo = $request->dispositivo;
$momentoacceso = $request->momentoacceso;
```